# Cassandra throttling workload

Tags: performance, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver, throttling

I've been recently attempting to send a workload of read operations to a 2-node Cassandra cluster (version 2.0.9, with rf=2). My intention was to send a number of reads at a rate that is higher than the capacity of my backend servers, thereby overwhelming them and resulting in server-side queuing. To do so, I'm using the datastax java driver (cql version 2) to run my operations asynchronously (in other words, the calling thread doesn't block waiting for a response).

The problem is that I'm unable to reach a high-enough sending-rate to overload my backend servers. The # of requests that I'm sending is being somehow throttled by Cassandra. To confirm this, I've ran clients from two different machines simultaneously, and the total number of requests sent per unit time is still peaking at the same value. I'm wondering if there's a mechanism that is employed by Cassandra to throttle the amount of requests that are being received? Otherwise, what else might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The network bandwidth from Cassandra side is throttling the amount of requests that are being received.

As far as I know their is no other mechanism employed by Cassandra to prevent itself from receiving too much requests. Timeout Exception is the main mechanism that Cassandra use to avoid crashing when it is overloaded.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. The cassandra nodes are connected to each other as well as the client using a 10Gig link. I've monitored the network traffic while I'm running my experiments for both Tx/Rx and it never exceeds 100 mb/s. I'm thinking some other mechanism is the culprit here.

Comment: You can easily verify that your network bandwidth is not the problem by increasing the size of your inserted entries.

Comment: Similarly you can decrease this size to force cassandra pending requests.

Answer (score 1):

Each request received by Cassandra will be handled by multiple thread pools implementing a [staged event-driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_event-driven_architecture), where requests will be queued for each stage. You can use [nodetool tpstats](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTPstats.html) to inspect the current status of each queue. Once too many requests are about to overwhelm the server, Cassandra will shed load by dropping requests once queues are about to reach their capacity. You'll notice this by numbers shown in the dropped section of tpstats. In case no requests are dropped, all of them will eventually complete, but you may see higher latencies using [nodetool cfhistograms](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCFhisto.html) or WriteTimeoutExceptions on the client.

Comment: I've checked the codebase for Cassandra's threadpoolexecutor and my understanding is that the workqueue is practically unbounded (i.e. the maximum size is by default set to an arbitrarily high value). However, even assuming that this is not true, tpstats reports 0 blocked/dropped operations.

Comment: It's also important to note that the java driver client I'm utilizing is not timing out on any requests and that Cassandra's queues aren't exploding (i.e. they keep fluctuating between 0 and 300). However, despite all this, I can't manage to exceed a certain sending rate in my experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cassandra has multiple ways to throttle incoming requests. The first action on your part would be to find out which mechanism is the culprit. Then you can tune this mechanism to fit your needs.

The first step to find out where the block occurs, would be to connect to JMX with jconsole or similar and look at the queues and block values.

If I would hazard a guess, check MessagingService for timeouts and dropped messages between nodes. Then check the native transport requests for blocked tasks before the request even get to the stages.